# model based impute with Orange3

Tags: python-3.x, orange

I'm trying to convert my code from python 2 to python 3. I use Orange to transform missing data based on a decision tree model. I build the imputer with the train set and use it with the train and the test sets.

I'm struggling to find in Orange 3 the imputer constructor.

My code with Orange 2.7:

```
        imputer = Orange.feature.imputation.ModelConstructor()
        imputer.learner_continuous = imputer.learner_discrete = Orange.classification.tree.TreeLearner()
        self._orange_imputer = imputer(train_data)
        train_data = self._orange_imputer_values(train_data)
        test_data = self._orange_imputer_values(test_data)
```

In Orange 3 I don't find the constructor, the continuous and discrete lerners, etc.

I'll appreciate any help. Thanks!